Bluetooth is disabled when power adapter removed on laptop
Like title says, Bluetooth works as expected, but when I remove the power adapter Bluetooth is disabled.
Neither the GUI nor
$sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
has any effect in re-enabling.
I've looked through /etc/bluetooth/ conf files, nothing of note there, and I've looked at powersaver settings.
It's really annoying as I never used to have this problem, and now when I unplug the PC to go to a meeting my headphones, mouse and keyboard are all disconnected, and I can't reconnect until I plug the PC back in. Yes, plugging back in immediately enables BT again.
Where to look to fix this?
Happening on 2 PCs:
OS:     Xubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64
Host:   ThinkPad T460s & T470s
Kernel: 6.8.0-39-generic
Output from lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.166584] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.935215] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    3.829354] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    4.828021] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[    4.862753] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ca7b901d.0 8000C-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.612068] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    7.612099] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    7.612101] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.612106] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.612109] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.612115] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.754504] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[    7.758499] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[    7.758508] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[    7.758511] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[   93.504798] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   93.504805] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   93.504811] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   93.507752] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   93.614685] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[   99.668886] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   99.668898] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   99.668906] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  121.103845] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
[  121.108943] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[  122.321902] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[  122.321911] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[  122.321914] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[  122.321917] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[  122.321919] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[  122.321921] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  122.328727] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[  123.779460] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[  123.779864] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1417119 usecs
[  123.779919] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[  123.790885] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[  123.790899] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10743 usecs
[  123.791641] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[  123.795889] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[  123.796887] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[  123.798879] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[  123.798889] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[  123.798893] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[  123.843188] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[  123.893343] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[  325.188037] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[  325.188854] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[ 2360.742402] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 2360.749479] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 2360.749496] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 2360.749506] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 2360.749513] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 2360.749520] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 2360.749529] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 2360.764805] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 2360.965799] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-19)
[ 2360.965826] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[ 2360.965842] Bluetooth: hci0: FW download error recovery failed (-19)
[ 2360.965893] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[ 2360.965902] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-19)
[ 2360.965906] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 2360.965909] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 2841.859285] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 2841.866339] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 2841.866356] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 2841.866366] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 2841.866374] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 2841.866383] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 2841.866391] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 2841.883675] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 2842.012749] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-19)
[ 2842.013929] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[ 2842.013950] Bluetooth: hci0: FW download error recovery failed (-108)
[ 2842.014000] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[ 2842.014006] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-19)
[ 2842.014010] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 2842.014013] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 3863.463690] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 3863.470659] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 3863.470665] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 3863.470667] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 3863.470669] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 3863.470671] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 3863.470673] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 3863.477354] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 3865.251720] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 3865.252638] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1733595 usecs
[ 3865.252708] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 3865.264626] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11675 usecs
[ 3865.264634] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 3865.264722] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 3865.269647] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 3865.270665] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[ 3865.272644] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[ 3865.272653] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 3865.272657] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 3865.320933] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 3865.373738] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[ 4481.634610] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[ 4481.638262] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[ 4493.388251] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 4493.395267] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 4493.395288] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 4493.395290] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 4493.395292] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 4493.395294] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 4493.395296] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 4493.401906] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 4495.162605] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 4495.163231] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1720086 usecs
[ 4495.163402] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 4495.174240] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10714 usecs
[ 4495.174264] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 4495.174353] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 4495.178268] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 4495.179265] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[ 4495.181925] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[ 4495.181936] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 4495.181940] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 4495.231369] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 4495.338809] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[ 4561.109958] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[ 4561.110151] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[ 4590.519274] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 4590.526296] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 4590.526304] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 4590.526306] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 4590.526309] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 4590.526310] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 4590.526312] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 4590.533251] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 4592.159753] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 4592.160281] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1588939 usecs
[ 4592.160352] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 4592.172287] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11680 usecs
[ 4592.172288] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 4592.172393] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 4592.176292] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 4592.177312] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[ 4592.179796] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[ 4592.179805] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 4592.179808] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 4592.225552] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 4592.278707] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[ 5362.502110] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[ 5371.061112] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
[ 5371.061159] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI reset during shutdown failed
[ 5377.572637] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 5377.579647] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 5377.579654] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 5377.579656] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 5377.579658] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 5377.579660] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 5377.579662] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 5377.586216] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 5379.378854] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 5379.379619] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1751339 usecs
[ 5379.379695] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 5379.391625] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11682 usecs
[ 5379.391729] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 5379.391743] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 5379.395662] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 5379.396641] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[ 5379.398633] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[ 5379.398642] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 5379.398645] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 5379.446001] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 5379.603538] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[ 6491.803684] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
[ 6493.809471] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[ 6494.182022] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 6494.189016] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 6494.189022] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 6494.189025] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 6494.189028] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 6494.189030] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 6494.189033] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 6494.191640] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 6495.723229] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 6495.723953] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1496372 usecs
[ 6495.723990] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 6495.734987] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10768 usecs
[ 6495.734989] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 6495.735012] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 6495.739001] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 6495.740003] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[ 6495.741995] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[ 6495.742001] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 6495.742004] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 6495.786357] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 6495.974291] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[ 6882.034973] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 6882.041984] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 6882.041992] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 6882.041994] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 6882.041996] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 6882.041998] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 6882.042000] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 6882.048631] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 6883.692192] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 6883.692940] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1605749 usecs
[ 6883.693024] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 6883.704948] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11685 usecs
[ 6883.704967] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 6883.705061] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 6883.708969] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 6883.709968] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[ 6883.711955] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[ 6883.711966] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 6883.711970] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 6883.757306] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 6883.891837] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[ 8457.107794] usb 1-2: device firmware changed
[ 8457.363705] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[ 8457.491834] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[ 8457.491839] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[ 8457.491841] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[ 8457.491843] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[ 8457.491845] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[ 8457.491847] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[ 8457.495380] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[ 8459.102257] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[ 8459.102781] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1569718 usecs
[ 8459.102810] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[ 8459.113791] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10744 usecs
[ 8459.113806] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[ 8459.113825] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[ 8459.117805] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[ 8459.118864] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 14 week 44 2021
[ 8459.120853] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
[ 8459.120870] Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
[ 8459.120874] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[ 8459.169171] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[ 8459.270318] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)


Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
